# Why is my message lost when the ScheduledExecutorService shutdownNow

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, scheduledexecutorservice

In my web app, I submit a runable instance to the ScheduledExecutorService. In the runable instance, I receive message from **IBM MQ** by use **receiveNoWait** mehod and the session is in **CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE** mode. When I invoke the shutdownNow method of ScheduledExecutorService, the receive method sometimes loses a message **without invoking acknowledge method**. Is there some suggestion for me?

Here is the code to receive a message.

> try {
>   when the ScheduledExecutorService shutdownNow ,I can only see the first loginfo without any exception.
>
> > logger.info("获取消息");
> >
> > Message msg = consumer.receiveNoWait();
> >
> > logger.info("获取消息成功");
> >
> > return msg;
>
> } catch (Throwable e) {
>
> > logger.error("处理数据的时候出现异常", e);
> >
> > return null;
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

[shutdownNow()](http://www.skillim.com/scheduledthreadpoolexecutor/) method tries to interrupt running tasks. If receiveNoWait method had time to finish you get message, otherwise not. If you need running tasks to be finished you can use [awaitTermination](http://www.skillim.com/executorservice/) method of ExecutorService interface or methods of Future object(isDone(), get() ...) that is returned by submit method.